# Which is better to use for adding IEnumerable object?

Tags: asp.net, repository-pattern, dbcontext

I have found two ways to implement add operation on IEnumerable objects in repository pattern.

First is to use .`AddRange()` & pass the list in here. Or
Second is to convert my list to Array & use `.AddOrUpdate(ArrayObject)`.

Which is better to use if my intension is to remove foreach loop on IEnumerable items? Please help.

```
_context.DbSet<MyEntity>().AddOrUpdate(entities.ToArray());
```

Or

```
 _context.DbSet<MyEntity>().ToList().AddRange(entities);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AddOrUpdate** can be called with an array of new objects, so you can just create an array of type City[] and call context.CitySet.AddOrUpdate(cc => cc.Id, cityArray); once. In generated SQL, there should be Where condition.

In case of performance, you would like to read following

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21839455/194345

and look following:

```
context.BulkInsert(hugeAmountOfEntities);
```

Comment: Thanks @Web World, I have gone through this for the ways when am trying to implement this. And its really fair to use BulkInsert. But I want to know which is preferable when I compare in between AddOrUpdate with array or AddRange().

Comment: @Neha You can check with generated SQL of both (using SQL Profiler or VS debug windows) and get idea. As I said, AddOrUpdate should have Where in SQL command so AddRange should be better but not sure.

Comment: I find both sqlcommand is having Where. Will you please clarify more on what you mean by where in sql command. I mean the difference which I have to look into.

Comment: Compare both generated SQLs if both are same then both AddOrUpdate and AddRange would be same in your case.

Comment: Ok, I have same sql. Thanks :)